# Find string between char in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a basic query. I have a string like below:

```
on one off abcd on two off
```

I want to find out all the string between 'on' and 'off'
the result I am expecting here is 'one' and 'two'

I believe this is possible with sed..

I tried with  `sed 's/on\(.*\)off/\1/g'`   but this returns `one off abcd on two`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, I think the easiest way is to use two sed processes:

```
echo 'on one off abcd on two off' | sed 's/\<on\>[[:space:]]*/\non\n/g; s/[[:space:]]*\<off\>/\noff\n/g' | sed -n '/^on$/,/^off$/ { //!p; }'
one
two
```

This falls into two parts:

```
sed 's/\<on\>[[:space:]]*/\non\n/g; s/[[:space:]]*\<off\>/\noff\n/g'
```

puts the `on` and `off` on easily recognizable, single lines, and

```
sed -n '/^on$/,/^off$/ { //!p; }'
```

prints just the stuff between them.

Alternatively, you could do it with Perl (which supports non-greedy matching and lookarounds):

```
$ echo 'on one off abcd on two off' | perl -pe 's/.*?\bon\b\s*(.*?)\s*\boff\b.*?((?=\bon\b)|$)/\1\n/g; s/\n$//'
one
two
```

Where the

```
s/.*?\bon\b\s*(.*?)\s*\boff\b.*?((?=\bon\b)|$)/\1\n/g
```

puts everything between `\bon\b` and `\boff\b` (where `\b` matches word boundaries) on a single line. The main trick is that `.*?` matches non-greedily, which is to say it matches the shortest string necessary to find a match for the full regex. The `(?=\bon\b)` is a zero-length lookahead term, so that the `.*?` matches only before another `on` delimiter or the end of the line (this is to discard data between `off` and `on`).

The

```
s/\n$//
```

just removes the last newline that we don't need or want.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser... but this is not printing anything at all.. can you please revisit

Comment: Do you, per chance, use Mac OS X?

Comment: The perl option seems to be working... now to the actual scenario where I would be doing testing     <replayqueue>abdc</replayqueue>ccc<replayqueue>lmn</replayqueue>dddd<replayqueue>xyz</replayqueue>       I would like to get abcd, ccc, xyz....

Comment: Honestly, if you wanted to extract data from XML, why didn't you ask a question about extracting data from XML? There are tools that make this much easier and more reliable. For example, with xmlstarlet you could just write `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//replayqueue/node()' -n`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version

```
awk -v RS=" " '/\<off\>/ {f=0} f; /\<on\>/ {f=1}' file
one
two
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(.*\) off.*/ \1³/;s/ off /³/g;s/ on /²/g;s/³[^²]*²/³²/g;s/^[^²]*²/²/;s/²/\
/g;s/.//;s/³//g'
```

- use `²`and `³` as delimiter (because POSIX sed does not allow a group rejection but a class) instead of `on`and `off`. Other character not used in the string could be use (avoid maybe meta char like `&`, ...)
- other action is to separate external content (remove) and reformat